# Python sharing a dictionary between parallel processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to share a dictionary between my processes as follows:

```
def f(y,x):
    y[x]=[x*x]                                                          

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    inputs = range(10)
    y={}                             
    result = pool.map(f,y,inputs)
```

The y returns {}. How can I make it work?

Thanks,

Comment: This sounds like a job for Redis!

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=redis

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This looks like you are using the `multiprocessing` module.  You didn't say, and that's an important bit of information.

The `.map()` function on a `multiprocessing.Pool()` instance takes two arguments: a function, and a sequence.  The function will be called with successive values from the sequence.

You can't collect values in a mutable like a `dict` (in the example, it's argument `y`) because your code will be running in multiple different processes.  Writing a value to a `dict` in another process doesn't send that value back to the original process.  But if you use `Pool.map()` the other processes will return the result from each function call, back to the first process.  Then you can collect the values to build a `dict`.

Example code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(x):
    return (x, x*x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool()
    inputs = range(10)
    result = dict(pool.map(f, inputs))
```

`result` is set to: `{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64, 9: 81}`

Let's change it so that instead of computing `x*x` it will raise `x` to some power, and the power will be provided.  And let's make it take a string key argument.  This means that `f()` needs to take a tuple argument, where the tuple will be `(key, x, p)` and it will compute `x**p`.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(tup):
    key, x, p = tup  # unpack tuple into variables
    return (key, x**p)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool()
    inputs = range(10)
    inputs = [("1**1", 1, 1), ("2**2", 2, 2), ("2**3", 2, 3), ("3**3", 3, 3)]
    result = dict(pool.map(f, inputs))
```

If you have several sequences and you need to join them together to make a single sequence for the above, look into using `zip()` or perhaps `itertools.product`.

Comment: How can I add one more arguments to f? I did def f(x,i):.... and then pool.map(f,inputs,1), but python does not like it. It returns f() takes exactly 2 arguments

Comment: `pool.map()` takes a function and a sequence.  The sequence can be a sequence of tuples or lists, and that would be how you would pass additional arguments.  I'll add one more example.

Comment: If you'd really like to have a shared dictionary between processes, have a look at Manager.dict in the multiprocessing module.