# Python sharing a deque between multiprocessing processes

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I've been looking at the following questions for the pas hour without any luck:

[Python sharing a dictionary between parallel processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025005/python-sharing-a-dictionary-between-parallel-processes)

[multiprocessing: sharing a large read-only object between processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659865/multiprocessing-sharing-a-large-read-only-object-between-processes)

[multiprocessing in python - sharing large object (e.g. pandas dataframe) between multiple processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487296/multiprocessing-in-python-sharing-large-object-e-g-pandas-dataframe-between/22487898)

I've written a very basic test file to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
from collections import deque
from multiprocessing import Process
import numpy as np


class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mem = deque(maxlen=4)
        self.process = Process(target=self.run)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.mem.append(np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))


def print_values(x):
    while True:
        print(x)


test = TestClass()
process = Process(target=print_values(test.mem))

test.process.start()
process.start()
```

Currently this outputs the following :

```
deque([], maxlen=4)
```

How can I access the mem value's from the main code or the process that runs "print_values"?

Comment: You need to read up on [*exchanging objects*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) or [*sharing state between processes*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes). Your child processes each get a forked copy of the deque, there is no further connection between them. You probably want a [managed `Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So by combining the code provided by @bivouac0 and the comment @Marijn Pieters posted, I came up with the following solution:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Queue


class testClass:
    def __init__(self, maxlen=4):
        self.mem = Queue(maxsize=maxlen)
        self.process = Process(target=self.run)

    def run(self):
        i = 0

        while True:
            self.mem.empty()
            while not self.mem.full():
                self.mem.put(i)
                i += 1


def print_values(queue):
    while True:
        values = queue.get()
        print(values)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = testClass()
    print_process = Process(target=print_values, args=(test.mem,))

    test.process.start()
    print_process.start()

    test.process.join()
    print_process.join()
```

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately `multiprocessing.Manager()` doesn't support `deque` but it does work with `list`, `dict`, `Queue`, `Value` and `Array`.  A `list` is fairly close so I've used it in the example below..

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Lock
import numpy as np

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.maxlen = 4
        self.manager = Manager()
        self.mem = self.manager.list()
        self.lock = self.manager.Lock()
        self.process = Process(target=self.run, args=(self.mem, self.lock))

    def run(self, mem, lock):
        while True:
            array = np.random.randint(0, high=10, size=5)
            with lock:
                if len(mem) >= self.maxlen:
                    mem.pop(0)
                mem.append(array)

def print_values(mem, lock):
    while True:
        with lock:
            print mem

test = TestClass()
print_process = Process(target=print_values, args=(test.mem, test.lock))
test.process.start()
print_process.start()

test.process.join()
print_process.join()
```

You have to be a little careful using manager objects.  You can use them a lot like the objects they reference but you can't do something like... `mem = mem[-4:]` to truncate the values because you're changing the referenced object.

As for coding style, I might move the `Manager` objects outside the class or move the `print_values` function inside it but for an example, this works.  If you move things around, just note that you can't use `self.mem` directly in the `run` method.  You need to pass it in when you start the process or the `fork` that python does in the background will create a new instance and it won't be shared.

Hopefully this works for your situation, if not, we can try to adapt it a bit.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this question. I've implemented your code but I'm getting the following error:

_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'weakref'>: attribute lookup weakref on builtins failed

I've tried moving the process outside of the class by using the following code, but without any luck:

test.process = Process(target=test.run, args=(test.mem, test.lock))

Comment: I've solved it using part of the code you provided and the hint @Marijn Pieters gave me. I'll post my sollution below :)