# How to get passed parameters to return values in multiprocessing Pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

For example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

numbers = []
for i in range(100):
    numbers.append(i)

def add_one(number, new_numbers):
    new = number + 1
    new_numbers.append(new)

new_numbers = []
process_pool = Pool(2)
add_one_helper = partial(add_one, new_numbers=new_numbers)

process_pool.map(add_one_helper, numbers)

print(new_numbers)
```

I suppose the new_numbers will print: 1, 2, 3, 4..., but it is empty in print(). How to get new_numbers to be populated after the call?

Comment: Probably need to join or something

Comment: If i add process_pool.join(), it will error: 'ValueError: Pool is still running'

Comment: Could be caused by [python - Why multiprocessing.Pool cannot change global variable? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53878553/why-multiprocessing-pool-cannot-change-global-variable)

Comment: Either way this is completely the wrong way to use `Pool.map`. Why can't you do it the normal way?

Comment: This answer doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025005/python-sharing-a-dictionary-between-parallel-processes/11025090#11025090, TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Comment: @user202729 what's the normal way? please write an answer. The linked answer gave an error.

Comment: Read the documentation, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First an observation. You have:

```py
numbers = []
for i in range(100):
    numbers.append(i)
```

This is using a loop to create a list with values 0, 1, 2 ... 99. But you could have just as easily and more efficiently specified:

```py
numbers = list(range(100))
```

But in fact the *iterable* argument being passed to the `Pool.map` method doesn't need to be a list (it will, however, be automatically converted to a list if it does not support the `__len__` method). So instead of creating the `numbers` list, you could have simply passed instead `range(100)` as the *iterable* argument to the `map` call. Now on to the question at hand:

The `Pool.map` method returns a list of all the return values from calling the worker function (`add_one` in this case). So you just need to have `add_one` *return* the value it wants appended to the new list:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def add_one(number):
    return number + 1

process_pool = Pool(2)
new_numbers = process_pool.map(add_one, range(100))
print(new_numbers)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
```